# Memory allocation with Marshal.AllocHGlobal

Tags: c#

When allocating memory from unmanaged process memory using Marshal.AllocHGlobal will the allocated memory address not change during the life of the application?

Am I correct in assuming that the memory block will exist until I call Marshal.FreeHGlobal and its address is unchanged?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is a safe assumption.

Comment: It depends - the main reason that these functions exist are for interoperability with native APIs where one side of the interop is allocating and the other side is deallocating. So if you call `AllocHGlobal` and then *pass that address to a native function that deallocates the memory* then no, it doesn't exist until you (erroneously) call `FreeHGlobal`.

Comment: How would you envision an address change to work? How could you possibly be informed? It's a pointer, not a reference. Note that from .NET 6 onwards, unless you have a requirement from an API somewhere that the memory *must* be allocated with `AllocHGlobal` (so `FreeHGlobal` will work), consider using `NativeMemory` instead.